# adding grid units in the native coordinate system

Tags: r, lattice, r-grid

I am creating `lattice` figures and annotating them with the `grid` package.  To set coordinates for my figures, I use `unit()` and related functions from the `grid` package.  It often helps to add units together, and this is typically no problem.  But I find that a strange problem arises when I try to add native units and the x- and y-scales for the current viewport don't have a lower bound of 0.  Here is a small example:

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)

# Expected result
xyplot(0:10 ~ 0:10, ylim=c(0,10))
myVP <- seekViewport("plot_01.panel.1.1.vp")  
y1   <- unit(5, "native") + unit(2.5, "native")
convertY(y1, "native")  # 7.5native, as expected

# Strange result
xyplot(10:20 ~ 0:10, ylim = c(10:20))
myVP <- seekViewport("plot_01.panel.1.1.vp")  
y2   <- unit(10, "native") + unit(5, "native")
convertY(y2, "native")  # 5native (why not 15native?)

# Other results with same lattice plot are as expected
convertY(unit(10, "npc")    + unit(5, "npc"), "npc")     # 15npc
convertY(unit(10, "mm")     + unit(5, "mm"),  "mm")      # 15mm
convertY(unit(10, "native") + unit(5, "mm"),  "native")  # ~10.35native
```

Further investigation reveals that `unit()` is subtracting `min(ylim)` when it does addition in native units.  So, in this example, I expect that `unit(10, "native") + unit(5, "native")` will yield a unit of `15native`, but it really yields a unit of (15-10)native.

Why does unit addition work this way with the native coordinate system, and why does it work a different way with other coordinate systems?

Comment: (1) The variable `y2` and `y4` in your first two calls to `convertY()` aren't defined at the time they're called. Did you mean `y1` and `y2`? (2) I suspect your question is answered  by `vignette("locndimn")`.

Comment: Thank you, @JoshO'Brien.  I did have a variable-naming problem in my original post.  And my question is answered, at least to a large extent, by `vignette("locndimn")`.  I'll soon post more about that.

Comment: In case you don't get around to answering this more fully: the way to get the behavior you expected is to use `convertHeight()` and `convertWidth()` instead of `convertY()` and `convertX()` (the last two of which are apparently implicitly called when a **grid** plotting function is passed a unit that's a sum of two `"native"` units). So, for example, in your `Strange result` section, `convertHeight(y2, "native")` will evaluate to `15native`, the value you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Josh O'Brien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980833/josh-obrien) points to the answer in his comments, and Paul Murrell's "locndimn" vignette (run `vignette("locdimn")` provides the details.  A quantity like `unit(5, "native")` has one meaning if refers to a location in the coordinate system, and a different meaning if it refers to a dimension.  Murrell's rule is that "locations are added like vectors and dimensions are added like lengths," and this seems to account for the results that I got when adding units in the native coordinate system.

Specifically, in my example, using `convertHeight` produces the result that I expected:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(10:20 ~ 0:10, ylim = c(10:20))
myVP <- seekViewport("plot_01.panel.1.1.vp")  
y2   <- unit(10, "native") + unit(5, "native")
convertY(y2, "native")       #  5native 
convertHeight(y2, "native")  # 15native
```

Comment: Thanks for writing up this answer. For whatever reason, even now that I understand the difference in behavior, I find that Murrell's explanation in terms of vectors and dimensions clarifies nothing! But the examples in the vignette do make it clear what's happening, if one spends a few minutes patiently working out why they produce the results they do.